# Why is CLLocationManager class a part of MapKit?

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I only imported MapKit and UIKit. Then in my Code I used the class CLLocationManager

```
var locMgr  = CLLocationManager()
```

My Code works without any error.

But there is something wierd.
CLLocationManager is NOT part of MapKit Framework. CLLocationManager is part of CoreLocation Framework.
But anyway there is no error. It´s not consequent. I don´t understand how that works.

Answer (score 0):

MapKit relies on the CoreLocation framework for its functionality, and for types that CoreLocation provides like `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, `CLLocationDegrees`, and others. For this, it imports CoreLocation.

Because MapKit uses CoreLocation types in its public API, it also has to re-export the import of CoreLocation itself, making CoreLocation available to you even if you haven't imported it manually.

Comment: Can I see that in the Xcode Documentation that MapKit relies in CoreLocaion Framework?

Comment: @Eddi Unfortunately, the docs don't clearly spell out "Framework A relies on Framework B" quite so directly. The [About Location Services and Maps](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497) document discusses them together, but it's not so clear-cut. The real way to know for sure is that: 1) MapKit API directly references CoreLocation API, which would not be possible without importing it, and 2) if you look in the MapKit headers (e.g. `MapKit/MKPlacemark.h`) you'll...

Comment: ... see those imports directly (e.g. `#import <CoreLocation/CLLocation.h>`).